# Can you help me with a problem with my nav menu? the selection items is a drop menu but I cannot get it work properly

Tags: drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm having an issue with my nav menu. There are 3 items in the menu Home About and Services. The services item is a drop down menu and I'm having a problem getting it to display properly when I hover over it. I'm close but can't seem to get it right. It appears to me to be a problem with the hover. There is a section in the CSS for the drop down menu.

```
               <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6eab1538de.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>replit</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
           * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    /* utility classes */

    .btn {
      background:darkgrey;
      color:#fff;
      padding:10px 13px;

    }

    h1,h2,h3 {
      padding-bottom:30px;
    }

    p {
      line-height: 1.5rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      padding-bottom:20px;
    }

    .bg-light {
      background:#e3d8d8;
    }

    .bg-primary {
      background:#867e7e;
      color:#000;
    }

    /* navigation  */

    .container {
      margin:auto;
      max-width:1300px; 

    }



    li {
      list-style:none;
      padding:13px;
      font-size:1.3rem; 
    }

    ul {
      text-decoration: none;
      display:flex;

    }

    .content {
      display:flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      align-items:center;
      height:70px;
    }



    #navbar {
      height:70px;
      background:#333;

    }

    a {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#fff;

    }

    .content li a:hover {
      background:#e6e6e6;
      color:#000;
      padding-top:24.5px;
      padding-bottom:24.5px;

    }

    .logo {
      color:#fff;
    }

    /* dropdown manu  */
    .dropbtn {
      display:inline-block;
      color:white;
      padding-top:13px;
        padding-bottom:13px;
        padding-right:13px;

      text-decoration: none;

    }

    li.dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      position:relative; 
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        margin-top:8px;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: blue;
      padding:13px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    /* li a:hover, */
    .dropdown:hover {
      background:#e6e6e6;

    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;


    }
    /* this ensures that drop list is below drop item has to be block */
    .dropdown:hover, .dropdown-content {
      display: block;

    }









    /*showcase  */



    #showcase {
      background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6407570/pexels-photo-6407570.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400"); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      background-size:cover;
      height:400px;
      text-align:center;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
    }

    #showcase {
      display:flex:
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }

    .showcase-content h1 {
    /*   padding-bottom:30px; */
      color:#fff;
      font-size:2.5rem;
      font-weight:700;
    }

    .showcase-content p {
    /*   line-height: 1.5rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem; */
      color:#fff;
      font-weight: 800;
    }

    .showcase-content {
      background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

    /* company info */

    .info-content a {
      color:#000;
    }

    #company-info {
      height:400px;
    }

    #company-info .info-img {
      width:50%;
      min-height:100%;
      background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/5093029/pexels-photo-5093029.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400");
      background-size:cover;
      background-position:center;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;

    }

    .info-content {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      width:50%;
      height:100%;
      text-align:center;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }

    .flexclass {
      display:flex;
      height:100%; 
    }

    /*services section  */

    .box {
      width:25%;
      text-align:center;
      padding:15px;
      line-height:1.2rem;
    }

      .box h3 {
      padding-top: 6px;
    }  





        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <!--   navigation  -->
      <div id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="content">
            <h1 class="logo">JLG Enterprises</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="services.hmtl" class="dropbtn">Services</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Item1</a>
              <a href="#">Item2</a>
              <a href="#">Item3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
             </ul>
          </div>


      </div>
      </div>

    <!--Showcase  -->
      <div id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1 class="headclass">Our Services cannot be beaten</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem ipsam vel ut laborum obcaecati totam, necessitatibus reprehenderit nam quasi ad?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <section id="company-info">
        <section class="flexclass">
          <div class="info-img"></div>
        <div class="info-content bg-light">
          <h2 class="info-head">The History of our Company</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis doloremque magnam, non expedita earum culpa.</p>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        </section>

      </section>

      <section id="services" class="flexclass">
        <div class="box bg-primary">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-mosquito fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>Pest Services</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, architecto?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Read More</a>

        </div>
        <div class="box">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-droplet fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>Irrigation Services</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, architecto?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Read More</a>

        </div>
        <div class="box bg-primary">
           <i class="fa-regular fa-image fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>Landscaping Services</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, architecto?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Read More</a>

        </div>
        <div class="box">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-building fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>Commercial Services</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, architecto?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Read More</a>

        </div>


      </section>



    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover
```

.dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).